# Why does the following integral not evaluate?

Tags: numerical-integration, fourier-analysis, integral-equations

[image]I am a complete beginner to Mathematica. I am trying to evaluate a Fourier integral (see below). Here $\mu(\vec{r})$ is a mass density with units $[\frac{u}{mm^3}]$, and its Fourier transform is defined as

$\mu(\vec{k}) = \mu(\vec{k}_p, k_z) = \int_0^Rdr\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^ddz e^{-i\left(k_zz + k_p rcos(\phi)\right)}r\mu(\vec{r})$,

where the integral is evaluated in cylindrical coordinates and the $r$ is due to the Jacobi determinant.

```
FT[mu_, R_, d_, kz_, kp_] := 
 Integrate[r*mu*e^(-i*kz*z)*e^(-i*kp*r*Cos[\[Phi]]),
  {r, 0, R}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, {z, 0, d}]
FT[\[Mu], R, d, kz, kp]
```

I get the following errors:

```
Integrate::units: Integrate was unable to determine the units of quantities that appear in the input.

Equal::nord2: Comparison of \!\(\*TemplateBox[{\"0.25`\", \"\\\"mm\\\"\", \
\"millimeters\", \"\\\"Millimeters\\\"\"},\"Quantity\"]\) and 1 is \
invalid"

Integrate::idiv: Integral of Sec[\[Phi]]^2 does not converge on {0,\[Pi]}"
```

Comment: You need to use correct syntax for it to work. Try `FT[mu_, R_, d_, kz_, kp_] := 
 Integrate[
  r*mu*Exp[-I*kz*z]*Exp[-I*kp*r*Cos[\[Phi]]], {r, 0, R}, {\[Phi], 0, 
   2 Pi}, {z, 0, d}]`

Comment: `E` is $e$, `I`is $I$....

Comment: Ok, some error messages are now gone. However, the first one (unable to determine inputs) still prevails. But thanks so far.

Comment: can you show screen shot of what you get?  Here is mine  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LznC4.png)   no errors. Make sure to start with clean kernel.

Comment: @Nasser Added it to the question

Comment: You seem to have some additional code that you must have before but are not showing. Where did the units come from? Code posted should be complete and self contained. no one can see hidden code, From a clean kernel, you should get same result I showed in the screen shot.

Comment: Yes indeed, the $\mu$ is the problem. It is defined as ``` mu = 4.2288 x 10^21 u/mm^3```

Comment: If `mu` is a quantity it should be defined using [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html)

Comment: In this case you could try the integration without using units. Then afterwords replace $\mu$ in the result by its numerical value with units?

Comment: @Nasser Yes since $\mu$ is constant one can replace it afterwards. I have indeed defined it using Quantity, and wondered where the error comes from, but it is not critical for the moment.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. I would recommend that you formulate your questions before asking them, instead of incrementally presenting information to respondents. Also you will find the [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor of much use as you learn Mathematica.